# Android: setVisibility(View.GONE) reducing the font size and image size on the webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android application that hits the `WebView` and displays the content. But as per the requirement initially I should hide the `WebView` and later on I should show it to the user.

So, initially I call `setVisibility(View.GONE);` and hide the visibility of the `WebView`. And, then I call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to show the `WebView` to the user.

1)When I am doing in this sequence, the size of the content(font and images) on the `WebView` are getting reduced.

2)If I don't call `setVisibility(View.GONE);` and directly show it to the user then size of the content(font and images) on the `WebView` is bigger.

I want to achieve 2 scenario by initially hiding the `WebView`. Means I want to hide the `WebView` initially, and then show to the user with bigger sized content on `WebView`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got this working finally!!!

Instead of using setVisibility(View.GONE); to make the webview invisible, I am using setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);.

This way I was able to achieve the proper size of items on the webview. Dont know the exact reason for this mismatch, but it is working as expected with this change.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell just how much the sizes are changing, but have you tried using WebView.zoomIn/WebView.zoomOut? You can also set the default with [WebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultZoom%28android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity%29).

Comment: Zooming this way looses the clarity on webview. I want to understand the reason behind setVisibility api and the size of the content in the webview.

Comment: I wish I knew more about it. I have encountered a lot of weirdness using the WebView, though, and sometimes I end up looking at the [WebView source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/WebView.java) to try to figure it out. Honeycomb source isn't released, but this can be a good way to get some clues. SetVisibility may be overridden in WebView, or you may have to check out View -- I think grepcode links up to superclass methods.  Good luck~